# glBufferSubData same values different behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I found a weird behaviour in `glBufferSubData` when trying to update a `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER`.

In my scene there are 3 objects.

I use the following struct for my Material definition

```
#pragma pack(push, 0)

struct Material
{
    GLfloat diffuse[4];
    GLfloat ambient[4];
    GLfloat specular[4];
    GLint useTex;
    GLfloat shininess;
} material;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

After writing values to it I update the uniform buffer:

```
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(material), (void*)&material);
std::cout << "out usetex: " << material.useTex << "\n";
/*The terminal shows: 
    out usetex: 0
    out usetex: 7
    out usetex: 7*/
```

This is my fragment shader (simplified for debugging):

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) out vec4 outputF;

layout (std140) uniform Material {
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 specular;
    int useTex;
    float shininess;
};

void main()
{
    if(useTex == 1)
    {
        outputF = vec4(1.0);
    } else
        outputF = vec4(vec3(float(useTex), 0.0, 0.0), 1.0);
}
```

From previous tests I know that `diffuse`, `ambient`, `specular` and `shininess` were updated correctly and the correct information is rendered.

The shader draws three completely white objects (so `useTex` obviously is 1). But as you probably noticed from above, the values should be 0, 7 and 7.

As this didn't worked out I tried to update `useTex` manually.

```
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(material.diffuse)*3, sizeof(material.useTex), (void*)&material.useTex);
```

Which didn't change anything.

Then comes the weird thing. I tried the following:

```
GLint gi = *new GLint(0);
std::cout << "out gi: " << gi << "\n";
std::cout << "out usetex: " << material.useTex << "\n";
    /* gives:
       out gi: 0
       out usetex: 0
       out gi: 0
       out usetex: 7
       out gi: 0
       out usetex: 7*/
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(material.diffuse)*3, sizeof(material.useTex), (void*)&gi);
```

Which renders three black objects (as expected when you look at the shader).

```
GLint gi = *new GLint(material.useTex);
```

This one again renders three white objects...

So what's the difference between `*new GLint(material.useTex)` and `*new GLint(0)`? Both should be different from `1`, shouldn't they?

I already checked for OpenGL errors with `glGetError()`. There was no error.

You probably need more code. The following lines describe how I assign values to `material`. If you need even more I could add this information. But I can't think of anything more that could also be related to this problem.

```
std::map<std::string, Material> materials;
std::vector<Mesh> meshes;
std::vector<Buffer> buffers;
/*... Mesh file loading code ...*/
/*a new material was found (name: matKey):*/
if(...)
{
    materials[matKey].useTex |= DIFFUSE;
}
if(...)
{
    materials[matKey].useTex |= SPECULAR;
}
if(...)
{
    materials[matKey].useTex |= NORMAL;
}
/* for each mesh the following is called (The key exists! I checked that.)*/
meshes[meshIndex].material = materials[/*some key string*/];
/* After all mesh objects are filled with values the following loop copies the data to a Buffer object*/
for(size_t i = 0; i < meshes.size(); i++)
{
    buffers[i].assign(&meshes[i]);
}
/* somewhere in Buffer::assign(Mesh* m) the uniform buffer is generated and the material struct is copied to a internal variable*/
glGenBuffers(1, &materialBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, materialBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(m->material), (void*)&m->material, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, Shader::MATERIAL_BLOCK_BINDING_POINT, materialBuffer);
material = m->material; //material is an internal variable
/* the class Buffer has also a render() function which starts with the uniform loading code that was described earlier (glBufferSubData() ...).*/

/* The `1` that is outputted in the shader comes from the constructor Mesh::Mesh()*/
Mesh::Mesh()
{
    /* .. some initializing .. */
    material.useTex = 1;
}
```

Any tips how to solve this issue?

Comment: cast the int before sending to GPU to a char* ptr and print ptr[0].. to ptr[4]. Then Inside the shader use as RGB values the top 3 bytes:
outputF = vec4(int4(useTex&0xFF000000,useTex&0x00FF0000,useTex&0x0000FF00)/255.0f);

If useTex is not 1, then by outputting its color as RGB values may help you identify wich part of the buffer you are using and if there are padding or endian problems

Comment: as good abitute I would check somewhere in your code "alignof(T)" and "sizeof(T)" to check if they are 32 bit values (GL types just specify a minimum size!!) I would use uint32_t instead of GLint, or just drop std140 and do some work to query correct offsets from the shader for the buffer

Comment: Try to reproduce the effect in an SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/) you could post here in the  - unlikely - case that you don't spot that bug yourself while assembling that SSCCE. Btw - sth like this `GLint gi = *new GLint(0);` is a memory leak, although likely not connected to the bug you try to find.